# nodemon start errors on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, deployment, nodemon

I've been running into the same start error when I deploy onto Heroku. I know it has something to do with my start script but I can't seem to pin down the issue.

I'm running into this error on app start:

```html
2018-10-22T15:31:04.927032+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2018-10-22T15:31:04.944756+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2018-10-22T15:31:04.946982+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2018-10-22T15:31:04.804183+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-10-22T15:31:04.804198+00:00 app[web.1]: > Backend@ start /app
2018-10-22T15:31:04.804200+00:00 app[web.1]: > nodemon -e js,graphql -x node -r dotenv/config src/index.js
2018-10-22T15:31:04.804202+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-10-22T15:31:04.810881+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: 1: nodemon: not found
2018-10-22T15:31:04.817652+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! file sh
2018-10-22T15:31:04.818091+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2018-10-22T15:31:04.818534+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno ENOENT
2018-10-22T15:31:04.818822+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! syscall spawn
2018-10-22T15:31:04.820778+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Backend@ start: `nodemon -e js,graphql -x node -r dotenv/config src/index.js`
2018-10-22T15:31:04.821033+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
2018-10-22T15:31:04.821320+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2018-10-22T15:31:04.821464+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the Backend@ start script.
2018-10-22T15:31:04.821628+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2018-10-22T15:31:04.829156+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-10-22T15:31:04.829411+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2018-10-22T15:31:04.829659+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2018-10-22T15_31_04_823Z-debug.log
2018-10-22T15:31:09.008630+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2018-10-22T15:31:12.142111+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-10-22T15:31:12.142136+00:00 app[web.1]: > Backend@ start /app
2018-10-22T15:31:12.142138+00:00 app[web.1]: > nodemon -e js,graphql -x node -r dotenv/config src/index.js
2018-10-22T15:31:12.142140+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-10-22T15:31:12.151638+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: 1: nodemon: not found
2018-10-22T15:31:12.157445+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! file sh
2018-10-22T15:31:12.157635+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2018-10-22T15:31:12.157787+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno ENOENT
2018-10-22T15:31:12.157931+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! syscall spawn
2018-10-22T15:31:12.159057+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Backend@ start: `nodemon -e js,graphql -x node -r dotenv/config src/index.js`
2018-10-22T15:31:12.159155+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
2018-10-22T15:31:12.159323+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2018-10-22T15:31:12.159423+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the Backend@ start script.
2018-10-22T15:31:12.159520+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2018-10-22T15:31:12.164017+00:00 app[web.1]:
```

So it can't find nodemon, despite it being installed. Here's my package.json:

```js
{
  "name": "Backend",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon -e js,graphql -x node -r dotenv/config src/index.js",
    "debug": "nodemon -e js,graphql -x node --inspect -r dotenv/config src/index.js",
    "playground": "graphql playground",
    "dev": "npm-run-all --parallel start playground"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "2.4.3",
    "googleapis": "^27.0.0",
    "graphql-yoga": "1.12.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "8.2.1",
    "multer": "^1.4.0",
    "node-schedule": "^1.3.0",
    "nodemailer": "^4.6.4",
    "prisma-binding": "1.5.17",
    "winston": "^2.4.2",
    "nodemon": "1.17.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "dotenv": "5.0.1",
    "graphql-cli": "2.15.9",
    "nodemon": "1.17.3",
    "npm-run-all": "4.1.2",
    "prisma": "^1.6.3"
  }
}
```

and my procfile is `web: node src/index.js`

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like `nodemon -e js,graphql -x node -r dotenv/config src/index.js` is being called by something other than npm, which is causing the issue with `nodemon` being missing, regardless of whether or not `nodemon` is actually present.

Here are some things you can do to isolate the root cause of the issue:

1. Confirm that the app works locally, with and without `nodemon`.
2. Ensure that your Procfile starts with a capitalized `P` (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile#procfile-format)
3. Update the `web` directive in your profile to `npm start`

If the above changes don't work, run through the following:

1. Navigate to the root directory of your project, and start a remote session as follows: `heroku ps:exec`.
2. Once inside your app's dyno, run `npm ls`. If this fails, your dependencies haven't been installed properly (which looks like a Heroku issue)
3. If the above command succeeds, run `npm start` to confirm that the app can launch.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I actually found the problem (i was failing to push an updated package.lock file to heroku) but I found your answer could help someone else with it's explanation and clear steps.